# Group_by not available for tables with mixin columns [Astropy, Table]

Tags: python, mixins, astropy

I am trying to run this code:

```
from astropy.table import Table
from astroquery.nasa_exoplanet_archive import NasaExoplanetArchive

exoplanets = NasaExoplanetArchive.get_confirmed_planets_table()
df=exoplanets.group_by('pl_orbsmax')
print(df)
```

And get the error:

> NotImplementedError: group_by not available for tables with mixin
>   columns

I want to simply extract data according to entries in specific columns. How can I convert this table to a format where I can use "group_by"?

I tried to restrict the columns to just a few which I am pretty sure are not mixin, eg:

```
subset=exoplanets['pl_discmethod','pl_orbsmax', 'pl_bmassj', 'st_mass']
```

but got the same error. I tried to converting to pandas, but that did not work either.

Comment: Related to my answer below, I was able to successfully run your example with no errors using astropy 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping of mixin columns is implemented as of astropy 3.1:

```
In [3]: t = Table([[1,2], Time([1,2], format='cxcsec')], names=['x', 'time'])

In [4]: tg = t.group_by('x')

In [5]: tg.groups[1]
Out[5]: 
<Table length=1>
  x         time      
int64      object     
----- ----------------
    2 2.00000000000351
```

By the way, you can definitively check for mixin columns with the `has_mixin_columns` property:

```
In [7]: t.has_mixin_columns
Out[7]: True
```